# How to get all pipelines activities in a single call in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I would really appreciate it if someone could  really help me out as I have struggled with this for almost 4 weeks. I have seen few examples here but different from my requirement

I have about 120 pipelines in my azure data factory and I have managed to get all the pipeline runs information stored in our ADSL gen 2 as parquet format, however  I need to get the activities in each of these pipelines stored in another parquet files so we could access the information using PBI. Each pipeline has about 5 activities each in it and I would like to capture these activities.

The "Get pipeline run" activities gets all pipeline runs including the pipelineRunId and I would like to pass each pipelinerunId to the "Get pipeline activities" so It can list of all the activities in each pipeline.

Thanks a lot

[data factory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ4G9.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a coincidence, I'm actually researching on how to do this myself. I want to link nested pipeline runs to the parent activity although I was able to store mine in a table in an sql database.

Comment: This does not read like an answer. Please post this type of response as a comment in future. If you are proposing your database solution as an answer then you should say so, and provide details on how others can implement your solution.

Comment: I found a solution around it...